# jQuery window.load doesn't modify dom elements created with other javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, window-load

Im using jQuery to modify html that has been created with other javascript. If I make the jQuery run when I click a button everything works fine.

However if I run the jQuery on window load it doesn't do anything. By adding an alert it seems its run before the other javascript has finished created html on the page. How can I make my jQuery run after all other javascript has finished?

Note - im making a demo only, so performance and best practice aren't really an issue in this case. Thanks

UPDATE - here is my code:

```
<html>    
  <head> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>        
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../gmap3.js"></script> 
    <style>
        body, html {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
      .gmap3{
        margin: 20px auto;
        border: 1px dashed #C0C0C0;
        width: 320px;
        height: 450px;
      }
      #panTo{
        background-color: Pink;
        float: left;
        text-align: left;
        width: 200px;
      }
      .find {
        height: 10px;
        width: 10px;
        background-color: grey;
      }
      #start {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
      }
      #button-0 {
        display: none;
      }
      .two {
        background-color: white;
        display: none;
        white-space: nowrap;
        z-index: 999999;
        position: relative;
        right: -19px;
        top: -46px;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 10px;
      }
      .no {
        text-align: center;
        border:1px solid grey; 
        position: relative; 
        left: -22px; 
        top: -2px; 
        background-color: white; 
        width: 19px; 
        height: 32px;
      }
      .active {
        font-weight: bold;
      }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      $(function(){
      var points = [
            [54.618017, 3.48291],
            [53.618017, 2.78291],
            [52.618017, 2.48291],
            [51.618017, 2.28291],
            [50.618017, 1.88291],
            [50.218017, 1.48291],
            [50.118017, 0.439453]
        ];



        $('#test1').gmap3(
          { action: 'init',
            center:{
                lat:44.797916, 
                lng:-93.278046
            },
            onces: {
              bounds_changed: function(){
                $(this).gmap3({
                  action:'getBounds', 
                  callback: function (bounds){
                    if (!bounds) return;
                    var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest(),
                        northEast = bounds.getNorthEast(),
                        lngSpan = northEast.lng() - southWest.lng(),
                        latSpan = northEast.lat() - southWest.lat(),
                        i;
                    for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
                     // add($(this), i, southWest.lat() + latSpan * Math.random(), southWest.lng() + lngSpan * Math.random());
                      add($(this), i, points[i][0], points[i][1]);
                    }
                  }
                });
              }
            }
          }
        );

      });

      function add($this, i, lat, lng){
        $this.gmap3(
        { action: 'addMarker',
          latLng: [lat, lng],
          callback: function(marker){
            var $button = $('<span id="button-'+i+'"> ['+i+'] </span>');
            $button
              .click(function(){    
                  $this.gmap3({
                    action:'panTo', 
                    args:[marker.position]
                  });
              })
              .css('cursor','pointer');
            $('#panTo').append($button);
          }
        },
        { action:'addOverlay',
          latLng: [lat, lng],
          options:{
            content: '<div class="no no-'+i+'" >'+i+'<div class="two"></div></div>',
            offset:{
              y:-32,
              x:12
            }


          },

          events:{
            mouseover: function(overlay){
           //   $(overlay.getDOMElement()).children().css('backgroundColor', '#0000FF');
            },
            mouseout: function(overlay){
           //   $(overlay.getDOMElement()).children().css('backgroundColor', '#00FF00');
            }
          }








        });
      }







      $(document).ready(function() {
      //$('#start').live("click", function() {
      //  $(window).load(function () {




                $('#button-1').html('<p>1) Herne Hill</p>');
                $('#button-2').html('<p>2) Sloane Square</p>');
                $('#button-3').html('<p>3) Elephant and Castle</p>'); 

                $('.no-1 .two').text('Herne Hill');
                $('.no-2 .two').text('Sloane Square');
                $('.no-3 .two').text('Elephant and Castle');



            $('#button-1').live("click", function() {
                $('.two').css('display','none');
                $('.no-1 .two').css('display','inline-block');
                $('#panTo span').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });

            $('#button-2').live("click", function() {
                $('.two').css('display','none');
                $('.no-2 .two').css('display','inline-block');
                $('#panTo span').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });

            $('#button-3').live("click", function() {
                $('.two').css('display','none');
                $('.no-3 .two').css('display','inline-block');
                $('#panTo span').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });



            $('.no-1').live("click", function() {
                $('.two').css('display','none');
                $('.no-1 .two').css('display','inline-block');
                $('#panTo span').removeClass('active');
                $('#button-1').addClass('active');
            });

            $('.no-2').live("click", function() {
                $('.two').css('display','none');
                $('.no-2 .two').css('display','inline-block');
                $('#panTo span').removeClass('active');
                $('#button-2').addClass('active');
            });

            $('.no-3').live("click", function() {
                $('.two').css('display','none');
                $('.no-3 .two').css('display','inline-block');
                $('#panTo span').removeClass('active');
                $('#button-3').addClass('active');
            });



        });


    </script>  

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="start">start</div>

    <div id="panTo"></div>
    <div id="test1" class="gmap3"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Got an example? Have you tried `$(document).ready()` instead?

Comment: You could either place your code after the other javascript, or wait for the dom to be ready.

Comment: Hmmm, actually looking at it window load and document ready aren't all that different. Still, example code would be good.

Comment: The other code that needs to run and finish first uses $(function(){ which seems to be the same thing as dom ready http://api.jquery.com/ready/. My code does appear later in the document so is probably run after the first lot, but maybe its run before the first lot finishes.

Comment: As this is just a demo a manual delay of say 1/2 a second might not be perfect but would be good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also delay the execution of your script to make sure other libraries have completed their initialization.

Eg:

```
$(function(){

   setTimeout(function(){
     //your code in this block is executed after 500 ms

   }, 500);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you place your code **after** the external code, it will run after the external code is finished, because ready handlers uses a queue.

There is no reason to use `setTimeout`

```
$(function(){alert('external');});

//...
//... 
//...    
$(function(){alert('your code');});​
```

see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/k23vk/) DEMO

Comment: Hasn't fixed it for me. Im kind of guessing here, but could it be that although the 2nd load of code is being run after the 1st load, its not waiting until the 1st load has finished executing?